# Reliably determine if angular-ui modal is open or closed (shown or hidden)

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui

I'm looking for a method to reliably determine if the angular-ui modal window is currently open or closed.

The standard Bootstrap JS provides the 'shown' / 'hidden' events for this.

Right now I can only wrap the modal.close() function and set a variable to 'closed'. Furthermore I am removing the modal object an re-instantiate it when opened again.  But that does not cover the cases in which the user clicks on the backdrop or presses the ESC-key to close the modal.

Is there a clean way to cover these cases, too?

Comment: What is your real, functional use-case?

Comment: I am using a fork of the security service used in your angular-app: https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/security/security.js

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**TLDR:**
Include module `ui.bootstrap.modal` in your app, inject factory `$modalStack` in your controller/service/whatever and then `!!$modalStack.getTop()` is enough to know whether a modal exists on not.

**Detailed Solution:** 
I was facing the same issue and I came up with the following work around :

There is a factory called `$modalStack` which is defined in ui-bootstrap lib which handles the modals. Same service also has a method called `getTop()` which returns the top most modal in dom. (And a method `dismissAll()` to close all the modals). So I wrote a small module with some small functions.

```
var utilsModule = angular.module('utilsModule', ['ui.bootstrap.modal']);

utilsModule.factory('modalUtils', [
  '$modalStack',
  function ($modalStack) {
    return {
      modalsExist: function () {
        return !!$modalStack.getTop();
      },
      closeAllModals: function () {
        $modalStack.dismissAll();
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: typo in `$modalStack.dismisAll();`. Should be `$modalStack.dismissAll();`